# Remember privileges after redeploying tizen app

Tags: c#, .net, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm developing a Samsung Watch App (Wearable app) for Tizen 4.0. I have added a privilege for location in my manifest file: `http://tizen.org/privilege/location`
As of Tizen 4.0 there is a requirement that I need to ask user for permissions using `PrivacyPrivilegeManager` class.

```
PrivacyPrivilegeManager.RequestPermission("http://tizen.org/privilege/location");
```

When I accept, everything works fine however I'm being asked each time my app is redeployed. It doesn't matter if it's my device or emulator. I also tried to set it manually from watch settings and it is not saved. It seems like each time I redeploy my app, it is uninstalled, privilege settings are wiped out and then new app is installed. Is there a way to save privilege affirmation permanently?
It probably doesn't matter if it's .net, c or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is a known bug with the Tizen SDK and has already been reported to the maintainers in charge. Unfortunately you will have to wait for upcoming SDK releases.

Here's a temporary fix: instead of using GUI command (VisualStudio) to redeploy your tpk, you may want to try a CLI command **`sdb install _path_to_tpk_`** which doesn't remove but only replaces the old version.